# What's Wrong: rvest's Error 'in open.connection(x, "rb") and readHTMLTable ()`s "XML contents does not seem to be XML"?

Tags: r, xml, importerror, html-tableextract

I was trying to import (scrape) sets of tables on a news blog post online using xml2's read_html(), hence  `html.table()` and `XML::readHTMLTable()` functions.
I got no table or anything useful with

```
readHTMLTable("https://www.theabusites.com/197-nuc-approved-universities-in-nigeria-2021/",...,
               header=TRUE, stringAsFactor=FALSE)
```

#Note: not CSV or html tag. It returns
? unable to find the inherited method  for the function 'readHTMLTable' for signature " NULL"', also <XML contents does not seem to be XML.>
What can I do?
Also,
*rvest*, too, returns the error flag, "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server" - What is causing this error message?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to scrape a web page as XML?  That might be problematic.  But without details of both your code and your input data, it's going to be difficult to help you...

Comment: The code in the duplicate question seems to do the trick ; `library(xml2) ; library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.theabusites.com/197-nuc-approved-universities-in-nigeria-2021/" ;
page <- read_html(url) ; tables <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: @Limey,  right. I was trying to scrape a web page and it contains multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you @User20650, the trick didn't actually work and it warned that "no XML content found". I had to save the html page into my local computer, C: and read it from there. Thank you. It's really problematics scraping directly from online source -  many adverts, menu tab address and empty tables were what I got.

Comment: @IbiloyeAbiodunChristian ; just tried iust again and can confirm it loads 14 tables into a list (14 tables as each of the tables on the page are split)

Comment: Thanks @user20650, it works pretty well. I looked into the network, and re-run on another PC, a laptop. I got all the tables. I also use nuc.data<- url("https://www.theabusites.com/197-nuc-approved-universities-in-nigeria-2021/", " rb"); page<-read_html(nuc.data); page. Thanks so much

Comment: good stuff; glad you got it working